# UserDefaults have different values within same app group

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults, appgroups

I have App+Extension and I made shared storage like this

```
extension UserDefaults {
    static let suiteName = "group.myApp"
    static let extensions = UserDefaults(suiteName: suiteName)!

    private enum Keys {
        static let personNames = "personNames"
    }

    var personNames: [String] {
        get {
            guard let array = UserDefaults.extensions.array(forKey: Keys.personNames) as? [String] else {
                return []
            }
            return array
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.extensions.setValue(newValue, forKeyPath: Keys.personNames)
        }
    }}
```

But when I debug app I see memory adress **A** and right values (because I put values through Main app but when I debug extension I have memory addres **B** and no values inside.

I am using same AppGroup on both Main and Extension app and I access data like this

```
   let personNames = UserDefaults.extensions.personNames
```

Is it problem that I am using free Apple Id account? I have possibility to create groups with this account so I doubt.

Comment: Don't use `setValue` method you should use `set(yourObject, forKey: "yourKey")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found solution. I made new group with format goup.com.company.appName.sharedStorage and also I use that as suitName and everything was working.

So maybe because of free apple account there was a problem with creating app groups (because it's automatic) or maybe because group.appName format is invalid.

Comment: I wan't to emphasize this from your answer:  use [group identifier] as suitName.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
Yes, you might need a paid Apple developer account because you have to enable the App Group feature which is associated to your app id.

**Original answer:**
You might need to call `synchronize()` to write your data immediately to disk.

```
var personNames: [String] {
    get {
        guard let array = UserDefaults.extensions.array(forKey: Keys.personNames) as? [String] else {
            return []
        }
        return array
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.extensions.setValue(newValue, forKeyPath: Keys.personNames)
        UserDefaults.extensions.synchronize()
    }
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for comment, but it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, but I enabled app groups as you can see it should be enough https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your "App Groups" section under "Capabilities"?